# How to change Array with one big string into an array with multiple indexes

Tags: c#

I am getting back an array of emails. It is an array but it is just one long string of emails separated by commas.

```
string[] emails - is returning an array of emails but it is just one string. 
emails = {"fjdksalg@gmail.com, jkgior@gmail.com, fjkgftroe@gmail.com,"}
```

How can i get these emails separated into individual strings?

Comment: [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: `var actualEmails = emails[0].Split(',');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string.Split() to separate a string by a specific character.

```
string longString = "fjdksalg@gmail.com,jkgior@gmail.com,fjkgftroe@gmail.com";
string[] emailArray = longString.Split(',');
```